# "Cyclic regions" in undirected graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Recently I needed an algorithm to find "cyclic regions" — my term – in undirected graphs.  Intuitively, a cyclic region is a set of nodes through which there exist one or more (undirected) cycles — but specifically, a *maximal* such set, that includes all cycles that contain any of the nodes.  More formally, I would suggest this definition: a cyclic region is a maximal subset of the nodes in the graph such that every node in the set has at least two neighbors that are also in the set.

The similarity to strongly connected components of directed graphs is pretty obvious, and indeed, a small modification to Tarjan's SCC algorithm suffices to find these cyclic regions.

But I was surprised that I couldn't find any prior reference to this concept either here on or Wikipedia.  My questions, then: is there a standard term for it?  Is my definition the usual one, and if not, do you see any problems with it, or would you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Try googling $k$-core of a graph[ $k$ is a positive integer]. You are in particular referring to the $2$-core of a graph i.e., $k=2$ for your application. At least that is what I am inferring.

Comment: I didn't explain what I meant very well.  Edited.

Comment: I understand my confusion now.  Mike is right: the formal definition I offered is that of the 2-core.  What I had in my head, though, was actually a slightly different definition: a subgraph in which every edge participates in at least one cycle.  I found this definition that clarifies the difference: "The 2-core is the union of all edges which form part of some cycle, and any edges which lie on a path between two edges which both form part of some cycle."  I was overlooking the latter possibility.